# XPath finding root element tags

Tags: xpath

I have the following xml doc

```
<root>
 <subject>This is the subject</subject>
 <email>
    <subject>Email's Subject</subject>
 </email>
</root>
```

How do I only select the 'subject' tag under the root element?  I do not want to get the subjects from the 'email' nodes.

Thanks!

EDIT:  Also, because the 'root' element is dynamic, how do I create the xpath without specifying the 'root' tag?  I've tried /subject,  //subject and //*/subject.  None have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/*[name()=$name]/subject` where `$name = 'root'`

`/*/subject` if you don't care about the document element name.

Comment: I thought I tried that path.  Ill update response as soon as I can